# Is there a way to have nested components inside of Formik fields?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

I have a Formik Form, that I am trying to get the value from a react-select element, into my Formik object.

Whenever I try to do this however, I get an error stating:

> Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children`
> nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML'

I understand this is because my source code is nested as shown below:

```
<Field name="state">
          <Select
              placeholder="Select State"
              value={myState}
              options={DataJSON}
              onChange={handleStateChange}
              getOptionLabel={(x) => x!.name}
              getOptionValue={(x) => x!.name}
             
            />
           </Field>
```

Is there a way, that I can insert my React-Select element into a formik field?

Comment: Try to not let the event bubble up to the Field element. Use event.stopPropagation(). That's how I fixed a similar error for myself.